# glDrawArrays sometimes draws black

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I'm using the following code to draw a green line at some specified coordinates

```
GLfloat colors[] = {0,1,0,1, 0,1,0,0.5};        
CGPoint v[] = {{p1.x, p1.y}, {p2.x, p2.y}};                

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

glLineWidth(10);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &v);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, &colors);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 2);

glDisableClientState(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

The problem is that once in a while even if the draw method gets called, the line turns black or does not get drawn entirely. i've checked the coordinates i pass and they seem fine.
Is there something that i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_LINE_SMOOTH` has ***never*** been an acceptable argument to [`glEnableClientState()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glEnableClientState.xml).

Comment: so what should I be using instead ?

Comment: Please try, glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the source of the problem, and you might have noticed it already, but isn't it correct to pass arrays to the functions without '&' or with '[0]'? i.e.

```
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &v);     // --> &v should be v, or &v[0]
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, &colors); // --> colors, or &colors[0]
```

Also, `glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);` seems the correct syntax.